# Mutable props issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Having read other questions on here it would seem that the props object used to be frozen, yet I seem to be able to mutate it:

```
class PropChange extends React.Component {
  render(){
    this.props.name = 'John';
    return <p>hi {this.props.name}</p>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<PropChange name="Frank" />, document.getElementById('mount'));
```

The same is true in a functional component. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/jmsherry/pen/dyYwKqW?editors=0011)

Can anyone explain this behaviour and how to make them immutable?

EDIT: So, I've investigated further. Have a look at [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-roentgen-m9pkt?file=/index.js) vs [codepen](https://codepen.io/jmsherry/pen/dyYwKqW?editors=0011), on the lines where I've logged out: `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(props, "name")` - it's writable on codepen but not on codesandbox! Anyone know why??

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the props, they are a plain objects. The fact that it's immutable helps to build the mental model of no such thing as two-way binding - the only way to propagate data up from the child to the parent is to use an updater callback.

Btw `PropChange2` in your example does not disprove immutability (`PropChange` does). `name` isa string, which is a primitive type, when you destructure in your parameters, it's a syntactic sugar for

```
var name = props.name;
```

By reassigning this value, you're not mutating it, you're overwriting the value.

If you're concerned about immutability / safety I'd advise to use TypeScript and ESLint with a proper strict enough setup. This kind of rules are better to be only enforced during development / compilation time.

Comment: Sorry, yes, you're right. I de-structured on a reflex. I've updated the codepen to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

The props object is a regular Javascript Object, therefore it is mutable. You can freeze an object using [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze).

I'd also like to note that any changes only apply within the component scope:

```
class PropChange extends React.Component {
  render(){
    console.log(this.props.name); // => Frank
    this.props.name = 'John';
    console.log(this.props.name); // => John
    return <p>hi {this.props.name}</p>
  }
}

const props = { name: 'Frank' };

ReactDOM.render(<PropChange {...props} />, document.getElementById('mount'));

console.log(props.name); // => Frank
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) to enforce immutability on an object's properties. However, if your `props` contain data structures as values, they will still be mutable.

```js
const props = {name: "John", height: {feet: 5, inches: 10}}
Object.freeze(props)

props.name = "won't let this happen"
props.name //"John"

props.height.feet = "will let this happen"
props.height.feet //"will let this happen"
```

Just make sure to freeze your nested data structures if you want full immutability.

Answer (score 0):

Mutable state and Immutable props are just pattern in react. 
In React, It isn't intended to mutate props or and make state immutable.

Although, It is a just javaScript that works how it is designed.
Objects are mutable in JavaScript.

So, I recommend you to not freeze props or not to make it mutable. It is not recommended by React officially.

You might break the react's working in your application if you do this unintended change.